# Rrdkit - Error while using install_github/devtools/timeout issue

Tags: r, timeout, devtools, revolution-r, rdkit

**System :** Linux - CentOS 6.5

**R Version :** 3.2.3 (64 bit)

I have the same Error exposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311872/error-while-using-install-github-devtools-timeout-issue) :

```
>devtools::install_github("pauca/rrdkit/rrdkit")
 Downloading GitHub repo pauca/rrdkit@master
 from URL https://api.github.com/repos/pauca/rrdkit/zipball/master
 Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
 Timeout was reached

>traceback()
13: .Call(R_curl_fetch_memory, url, handle)
12: curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle)
11: request_fetch.write_memory(req$output, req$url, handle)
10: request_fetch(req$output, req$url, handle)
9: request_perform(req, hu$handle$handle)
8: httr::HEAD(src_submodules, , auth)
7: github_has_remotes(x, auth)
6: remote_download.github_remote(remote, quiet = quiet)
5: remote_download(remote, quiet = quiet)
4: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
3: vapply(remotes, install_remote, ..., FUN.VALUE = logical(1))
2: install_remotes(remotes, quiet = quiet, ...)
1: devtools::install_github("pauca/rrdkit/rrdkit")
```

I tested maddy2u's solution but it does not work on my station with `options(download.file.method = "wget")` or `options(download.file.method = "libcurl")`. I tried a lot of things but I have no ideas to solve that.

Any help is welcome and thanks in advance.