# Cannot install mlr package on work machine which uses a proxy server

Tags: r, installation, mlr

I have R and R studio on my work PC and am trying to download and use the unbalanced package.
Everytime I try however it tells me that the dependency mlr will not be downloaded.

```
 install.packages("mlr")
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘mlr’
  These will not be installed
```

I read on another thread that this might be because Rtools was not uptodate. Checked that.

```
install.Rtools()
Loading required namespace: devtools
No need to install Rtools - You've got the relevant version of Rtools installed
```

Tried to download via github and it timed out, though I'm questioning if I need to log in first to allow this to work.

```
devtools::install_github("mlr-org/mlr")
Downloading GitHub repo mlr-org/mlr@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/mlr-org/mlr/zipball/master
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached
```

The really odd thing is that I can download other packages on this PC and on my personal PC it downloads it no problems.

**EDIT** I checked the mirror that I'm using on both machines and it's the same (http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin) so that cannot be the issue.
Also I used the adjust options suggested in the answer to the first comment below and that has failed.

```
options(download.file.method = "wininet")
> devtools::install_github("mlr-org/mlr")
Downloading GitHub repo mlr-org/mlr@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/mlr-org/mlr/zipball/master
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached
```

Any thoughts?  I'm a bit lost and can only think to look for another package to rebalance my data.
J

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while using install\_github | devtools | timeout issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311872/error-while-using-install-github-devtools-timeout-issue)

Comment: I can download other packages though and also tried other mirrors. However that was this afternoon when it adjusted the whole of cran was down so will give that a go tomorrow too.

Comment: Just to confirm that I tried the change of mirrors and it didn't work

Comment: You can also simply download the entire repository from github and install locally.

Comment: Tried that and gave errors... Will pay errors tomorrow in case I did it wrong.

Comment: Meant to add that for the same issue with the scales package today. Other packages are fine

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error after updating to `R 3.3.0`. The cran current rel/dev builds seem to be unavailable, dunno if that's the reason, but I got it working by downloading the `.zip` 2.8 oldrel directly from [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlr/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

we were a bit slow with the release package, and multiple changes in devtoools, testthat and ggplot didnt help with that.

everything should work now.

in the future also consider shouting at us in our github tracker.

best

bernd